# Calculating measure at a certain grain in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a power  BI report with dataset (week, business unit, SKU, Inbound, Outbound). I have below measures:

```
Subtract = Inbounds- outbounds

Non Ngetiave MEAS1 = IF (inbounds-outbounds)<0,0,(inbounds-outbounds)
```

While calculating `Non Ngetiave MEAS1`, I want to show the "overall" value to be the sum of individual `Non Ngetiave MEAS1` calculations at sku-week grain. 
If you look at the PBI, currently it shows *1683*, what I would want is *2173* which is the sum of individual `Non Ngetiave MEAS1`.

It works when I am using a calculated column. I want it to work with measures to because in my actual data set, all these are measures.

```
NonNegMeas1 = 
    SUMX(
        VALUES('Table'[SKU] ),
        CALCULATE(
            CALCULATE( 
                 if('Table'[Subtract]<0,0,'Table'[Subtract]),
                 ALL('Table'[SKU]),
                 SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[SKU])
             )
        )
    )
```

[PBI LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HYTtaefbExtdVIl9Es0tZjQXZU1UkOXW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, i've got confused on what you want toa chive actually. Could you please elaborate on that? TBH, having values, all, summarize and double calculate in a single calculation will bring a lot of issues and confusion.

Comment: Updated the post to make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Why can't you just sum the calculated column (the recoded one) exactly? Is it because in an actually dataset you don't recode it on a row basis?

Comment: Exactly. In the actual dataset, all these are measures and not columns. That's why I am trying to achieve this in measure

Comment: @PavelKlammert Any recommendation?

Comment: sorry for inactivity. I thought this has been answered by RADO, but i guess i've been mistaken. Please, check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but:

```
solution = SUMX(
SUMMARIZE(
    ('Table'),'Table'[SKU],'Table'[Week] ),
     if('Table'[Subtract]<0,0,'Table'[Subtract])
    )
```

The only change is the additional group by column (week) going into the summarize function, which changes the calculation. Without the C SKU has Outbound - inbound < 0, therefore it seems, that the 1683 result is actually correct.
Please, let me know if that solves your issue. Thanks